# Convergence of linear regression coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, regression

Consider a sequence of linear regression problems: 
$$
Y^{(n)}_n = X^{(n)}_{n \times p } \beta_{p}^{(n)}
$$
where $p$ is fixed and $X^{(n)}_{n \times p }$  is full rank for all $n$.

My question is:
What is the general topology (Banach space, locally convex space, etc) in which we can prove the convergence of $\beta$ parameters? 
$$
\beta^{(n)} = (X^{{(n)}\top} X^{(n)})^{-1} X^{{(n)}\top} Y^{(n)}.
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $\beta$ is always a $p$ dimensional vector, you don't have much choice: $\mathbb R^p$ is a TVS, is a Banach space, is a Frechet space, but this does not influence the convergence of the $\beta$ parameters. Accuracy of the regression model and accumulation of extra evidence does.

Comment: Is it possible that it exists an operator $P_X: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ on a Banach space such that the limiting $\beta$ is computed as  $(P_X^{*} P_X)^{-1} P_X^{*} Y$ where $Y$ is the limit of $Y^{(n)}$?